# vuetify 3 global defaults for v-text-field hide-details

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I'm trying to set the global default for [hide-details](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/#props-hide-details) for a `VTextField` (`v-text-field`) but the syntax I'm using below isn't correct because it doesn't like -'s in the typescript:

**vuetify.ts**:

```
const vuetify = createVuetify({
  defaults: {
    VTextField: {
      density: "compact",
      variant: "outlined",
      color: "primary",
      hide-details: "true"
    }
  }
});
```

Do I need to escape the dash in `hide-details` somehow for this to be syntactically correct?

The error I'm seeing is:

```
vuetify.ts:47:10: ERROR: Expected "}" but found "-"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `camelCase`. Vue is smart enough to compile it to `kebab-case` when parsing the DOM template:

```
const vuetify = createVuetify({
  defaults: {
    VTextField: {
      density: "compact",
      variant: "outlined",
      color: "primary",
      hideDetails: true
    }
  }
})
```

Also note [`hide-details`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/#props-hide-details) expects either a `boolean` value or the string `"auto"`.
The string `"true"` is not a valid value for it, according to documentation ***<sup>1</sup>***.

---

And, if that doesn't work (I would be extremely surprised if it didn't), and simply to answer the more general question here, you can always wrap the key of an object into quotes to guard against special chars being parsed as something other than key contents, so this should work, as well:

```
const vuetify = createVuetify({
  defaults: {
    VTextField: {
      density: "compact",
      variant: "outlined",
      color: "primary",
      "hide-details": true
    }
  }
})
```

but, again, it shouldn't be necessary in this particular case.

---

***<sup>1</sup>*** - technically, that might be wrong, but it's coincidental: I've previously seen cases where Vue parses the string `"true"` to the boolean `true` when given as the value of a field expecting a boolean. But it's possible that the value passed is cast to Boolean if it's not one of the accepted string values (e.g: `"auto"` in this case), which would mean the string `"false"` will also be parsed as `true`, not as `false`. Main takeaway: always consult documentation about the accepted values for a prop.

Comment: `hideDetails: "true"` does in fact work!  I think I originally tried that in all lowercase and it does not.  I did also try `"hide-details": true` originally and that also did not work.  Thanks @tao

Comment: I find it weird that `"hide-details": true` didn't work. Nonetheless, I'm happy I was able to help you fix the issue. And not working for `hidedetails` makes sense, as it will never be parsed as `hide-details`, whereas `hideDetails` will. Vue will always parse `camelCase` to `kebab-case` for element attributes, it's part of DOM parsing. It's a Vue thing, not a Vuetify thing.